# what is wrong with my http request in javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I want to send a message to the server comprises of a few different sections. The goal is to send some x-www-form-urlencoded info with an image. I tried do sth similiar to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages

This is my js function to do that:

```
function sendPage() {
    var source = document.getElementById("pageContainer")
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer
    if (!source.hasChildNodes()) {
        alert("nie ma nic do wysłania")
        return
    }
    var DOMNodeInString = "content=" + escape(serializer.serializeToString(source))
    //    sendToServer("savePage.php", true, handleAndShow, DOMNodeInString);return
    xhttp.open("POST", "savePage.php", true)
    var boundary = "xxx"
    var body = "--" + boundary + "\r\n"
    var file = document.getElementById("imgSource").files[0]
    //wysyłam obrazek
    if (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
        body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='upload'; filename='" + file.name + "'\r\n"
        body += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"
        body += reader.result + "\r\n"
        body += "--" + boundary + "\r\n"
    }
    //wysyłam pozostałe pola formularza
    body += "Content-Type: multipart/x-www-form-urlencoded \r\n\r\n"
    body += DOMNodeInString
    body += "\r\n--" + boundary + "--"
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed; boundary=" + boundary)
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = handleAndShow
    alert(body)
    xhttp.send(body)
}
```

however, the function doesn't work. My php script is unable to receive $_POST["content"]. What should I change to improve the js script?

Comment: Have you tried analyzing the network activity with Firebug (FF), Web Inspector (Chrome/Safari) or Dragonfly (Opera)? What are the response headers, for example?

Comment: Respose headers:
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:20
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Sun, 14 Nov 2010 17:03:52 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3-2

the content is empty and that's not what I expect because savePage.php is 
<?
header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo $_POST["content"];
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to upload a file using an XMLHttpRequest.  You'll need to use Flash/Java or create a hidden iframe and do an actual submit.  I'd suggest using a javascript plugin for ["AJAX" file upload](http://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+file+upload).

Comment: That is what actually what am going to do. I have already dropped the idea that I can send file through xhr. I want only to understand what is wrong with my js except for reader.result equality to ""

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @tvanfosson answer, you are missing a creation of the xhttp object:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Use any debugger to see that the JS works without exceptions...

Comment: yes, you are wright. However, it is defined prior to the definition of the function sendPage() so it's not the case.